# Phonegap ajax call issue Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: ajax, cordova, cross-domain

i'm trying to call an asmx web service, i added the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the web.config, i added the asmx url in the phonegap whitelisting.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("ready",onDeviceReady);
        function onDeviceReady(){
          $.support.cors=true;
          $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            crossDomain:true,
            dataType: "json",
            url:"http://192.168.1.3:812/WebService1.asmx/ObtNegocios",
            data: '{}',
            success: function(msg) {                        
              for(i=0; i < msg.d.length; i++)
                {
                $("#details").append($('<li/>').append($('<a/>').attr("href","prueba2.html?id="+msg.d[i].id.Timestamp+"-"+msg.d[i].id.Pid+"-"+msg.d[i].id.Increment+"-"+msg.d[i].id.Machine).text(msg.d[i].nombre)));
                  console.log(msg.d[i]);
                   }
                   $('#details').listview('refresh');
                   },
                   error: function(msg) {
                   alert(msg.d);
                   console.log(msg);
                   }
                   });
        }
   </script>
```

the problem appear when i click a list item to see a more detailed information about it

OPTIONS file:///D:/workspace/pruebaPhonegap/assets/www/prueba2.html?id=1375817236-10972-15564611-8618666 Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/workspace/pruebaPhonegap/assets/www/prueba2.html?id=1375817236-10972-15564611-8618666. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

these are the errors thrown by the chrome console,

Comment: set access- origin * on config.xml

Answer (score 3):

Hi first test on real device , it will solve your issue .
check your confix.xml and add    **`<access origin="*" />`**
 if you need to test in browser use any local server (if php xampp or wampp).

Answer (score 0):

IF server Side is PHP you can add below line on the top

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');